# How to get the best graphical performance out of Java2D

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, java-2d

This question does not apply to libraries such as LWJGL, JavaFX, etc.  The goal here is to determine how to get the best performance out of Java2D.  More particularly, how to get the best performance out of Java2D to create visually appealing yet efficient 2D games.  I have come across quite a lot of practices: drawing directly onto a JFrame, overriding JPanel or JComponent, [overriding Canvas](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/113977-java-game-the-fastest-way-to-repaint-bis/) to provide some nice double buffering strategies, using a library (ehm), etc.

In the past, I have simply overriden a JPanel and its paintComponent method, and, in the end, it ran at a steady 35 FPS!  Not really the pinnacle of performance for a simple top-down 2D Java game (or maybe it is?).

*So, what is the best strategy to get every drop of performance out of Java2D?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Java's `Graphics2D` class to draw objects with nice performance, I recommend using [VolatileImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html). It is available since Java 1.4 and uses hardware accelerated processing (if possible) to render its stuff. It extends `java.awt.Image` so there are not so much changes for you, if you used `BufferedImage` or so before. But there are some tricky things using this class. For example before you render its content you need to check whether it is still valid, but usually it is not so hard to manage this stuff· But therefor you get pretty nice performance boost to your app, without the need to change a lot of code. :)

This [link](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java%3aTutorials%3aVolatileImage) should give you good advice using this class.